# Python decode not converting to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to read a string from serial line using the code below, python keeps attaching the b' prefix and newline or return suffixes despite my telling it to convert to regular code and strip those out.  Also, even if I send the text for 'FORWARD' to the device, it will not recognize the response.

Why wont python convert my text to regular format, and how do I get it to recognize my input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0',baudrate = 9600,timeout=1)

while 1:
    x=ser.readString()
    x = x.decode()
    x = x.strip()
    print(x)
    
    if x.find('FORWARD') >= 0:
        print("FORWARD")
```

I expect it to show my serial input without the b' prefix or any \r\n suffixes, just the text I sent.  I also expect it to recognize that the word "FORWARD" was in my input when I send that over the serial line.  It dont do that, it shows b'FORWARD\r\n' and dont recognize that FORWARD is in the text

Comment: What does `print(repr(x))` show exactly?

Comment: Where does the serial port get its data? Consider that `b"b'foo'".decode() == "b'foo'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think `decode('UTF-8')` might help. I am working with binary data as well and you should specify which form you want it to be decoded to.

`b'test'.decode('utf-8') == 'test' -> True`

If the problem roots in that your string is binary which contains binary string, such as `b'b"test"'` then you can solve it with:

`b'b"test"'.decode('utf-8').strip('b"') == 'test' -> True`